# Converting Date to GMT date format

Tags: java

Please help in converting data in format "**May 16, 2007 12:00:00 AM**" to GMT data format like 
"**2007-05-16T12:00:00.000+0000**" in java
Using following method

```
public  String getGMTMillis(Date time)
{
    if (time != null)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(time);
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        return "" + calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Take your title and use it in a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public String getGmtMillis(Date time)
{
    if (time == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return df.format(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking for the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time formats.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library uses that standard format as its default for `toString` method.

```
String dateTimeString = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Output will be something like:

```
2014-01-18T12:34.123Z
```